# Worker node - file system affinity to Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have a specific monitoring system with thousands of files kept **locally** ( no HDFS) on each monitored server. I want to use flink to query these files. If i create a worker node on each machine and they query a specific file, how will the master node knows to send this task to the node where the relevant file resides in ? One of my retirements is to minimize the network traffic and avoid moving data between nodes. Is there a way to "hint" it somehow ?

Comment: Small change in the grammar

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "...use Flink to query the files". You could create a custom [SourceFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction.html) that knows how to read from local files, which you then parse/process with Flink, and expose the results via [Queryable State](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html). If there's no partitioning in this stream, then all of these chained operators would run in the same slot on a Task Manager, and thus minimize network traffic.

You'd want to set the SourceFunction's parallelism equal to the number of nodes (and thus the number of Task Managers). But you still need to make sure that Flink doesn't wind up running two of the same SourceFunction on the same Task Manager, and thus on the same node, which wouldn't work for you.

In general Flink doesn't provide much support for precise placement of tasks. I think if you set the [taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#taskmanager-numberoftaskslots-1) to 1, then that might force it to deploy a separate SourceFunction (plus the chained operators following it) per Task Manager, but you'd have to give that a try.

Regards

-- Ken

Comment: Thanks Ken,  but im not sure how that helps me.   let me elaborate.
say i have  server one -  which have File 1 on it , as well as a taskManager.  
Server 2 which has  File 2 on it and a taksManager.     when i submit a job with the parameter of a file name.  i would like it to be sent to the proper task manager - where the  file is located.

Comment: At a high level, I'm not sure what you're proposing is a good use of Flink :) But you can broadcast a file name, so that it's sent to every operator. If you can ensure that each Task Manager has an instance of the operator running, then one of the operators on the machine where the file exists would be able to find/process it. But normally you'd (a) have a source function that just watches for new files, (b) a workflow that parses the file, and generates results with a "filename" field that you key on, and then you use that with Queryable State.